# Sync up photoshop canvas with mobile screen?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mobile, canvas, mobile-first

I was wondering if there is a way to sync up my photoshop canvas to my mobile phone so I can see live changes. I usually have it connected with android debugging to preview webpages that I make so that is no problem.

It would be awesome to view a realtime canvas on my mobile phone so I can preview what it will look like in reality. I know this won't be a perfect solution but it gives me a good idea about proportions and usability.

Hopefully somebody can help me out if such a thing even exists.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: This is the kind of question which might be a good fit for the proposed Graphic Design Software Support stack. Please see the proposal and follow it if you think it might be useful. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86994/graphic-design-software-support/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of different options

**Skala Preview** - Works only on Mac, mobile app works for iOS or Android

A short description from their website

> Skala Preview sends lossless, colour accurate image previews to any
>   iOS or Android device. Previews are pixel perfect. Colours are
>   identical to how the final app or website will look on the device.

Check out the website at http://bjango.com/mac/skalapreview/

**LiveView** - Works only on Mac and iOS devices.

A short description from their app store

> LiveView is a specialized network screen viewing application intended
>   as a tool to help designers create graphics for mobile applications.
>   It is also useful for creating quick interactive demos and experience
>   prototypes.

Check out the website at http://www.zambetti.com/

**Sketch** - Works only on Mac and iOS devices.

Sketch has a mirror option, you will need to download the companion app for your device

Comment: I tried Skala View but it is pretty laggy. When I do something even in a small photoshop document it takes about 3-5 seconds to reflect the changes. Even when I am using usb tethering like they suggest on their website for a faster connection. Can't use the others because I use mac and an android device.

Comment: @Stephan-v There’s a fair bit of data being transferred (Skala Preview sends uncompressed images), so a few seconds is probably the best you can hope for with a similar setup. We’re working on making it faster and more stable, but anything below ~2 seconds is difficult while maintaining quality.

Comment: @Marc Edwards have you thought about adding support for usb connection? Could that make it faster?

Comment: @Joonas: We sort of have USB support if you’re using Personal Hotspot via USB: http://bjango.com/help/skalapreview/personalhotspot/ Adding direct USB support isn’t easy and may not be possible while abiding by the App Store rules. We’ll do what we can though.

Answer (score 2):

**Astropad** http://astropad.com/

Turns an iPad into a little mini Cintiq. It not only shows you the canvas, but allows you to work on the tablet and changes are reflected, real time, on the primary computer. (and vice versa)

Mac only though.

Comment: Have you used Astropad? Does it really work as well as they say it does?

Comment: @Joonas yes. It's really a marvel. It does actually work as they advertise.

Comment: Afraid I don't have an iPad. Yet :P

Answer (score 1):

How about:

- [Real VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/products/android/) allows you to see anything on your desktop (even interact with it)
- [iDisplay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idisplay.virtualscreen) makes your android a second monitor (you can then use **Window → Arange → New View**)

Answer (score 0):

I use 'Silkscreen' every time you click save it shows up right away on your mobile

Answer (score 0):

A couple more to add to the plethora:

[Stand In](http://standin.io/) - for creating interactive prototypes

[Invision](http://www.invisionapp.com/) - also for prototyping but has a pretty good Photoshop mirror option (and it's free)